# Contact Form won't work

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I downloaded this website template from https://themewagon.com and can't get the contact form to work. I changed the information in the .php file for my personal info, but each time I try to send a message nothing happens except the page being refreshed. 
*(I had to translate some of the words so that they appear in French on my website)

**Jquery in Index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        inicializemap()

        $('#contactForm').on('envoyer', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var message = $("#message").val();
            var goodToGo = false;
            var messgaeError = 'Request can not be send';
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^(('[\w-\s]+')|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|('[\w-\s]+')([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);


             if (name && name.length > 0 && $.trim(name) !='' && message && message.length > 0 && $.trim(message) !='' && email && email.length > 0 && $.trim(email) !='') {
                  if (pattern.test(email)) {
                     goodToGo = true;
                  } else {
                     messgaeError = 'Revérifiez votre adresse courriel.';
                     goodToGo = false; 
                  }
             } else {
               messgaeError = 'Vous devez remplir tout les champs pour envoyer votre message.';
               goodToGo = false;
             }


            if (goodToGo) {
               $.ajax({
                 data: $('#contactForm').serialize(),
                 beforeSend: function() {
                   $('#success').html('<div class="col-md-12 text-center"><img src="images/spinner1.gif" alt="spinner" /></div>');
                 },
                 success:function(response){
                   if (response==1) {
                     $('#success').html('<div class="col-md-12 text-center">Your email was sent successfully</div>');
                     window.location.reload();
                   } else {
                     $('#success').html('<div class="col-md-12 text-center">E-mail was not sent. Please try again!</div>');
                   }
                 },
                 error:function(e){
                   $('#success').html('<div class="col-md-12 text-center">We could not fetch the data from the server. Please try again!</div>');
                 },
                 complete: function(done){
                   console.log('Finished');
                 },
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'js/send_email.php', 
               });
               return true;
            } else {
               $('#success').html('<div class="col-md-12 text-center">'+messgaeError+'</div>');
               return false;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Contact Form in HTML @Index.html

```
<section id="contact">
            <div class="container"> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="text-center color-elements">
                            <h2>Nous joindre</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8">
                            <form class="inline" id="contactForm" method="post" >
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 height-contact-element">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control custom-labels" id="name" placeholder="Votre nom" required data-validation-required-message="Veuillez écrire votre nom"/>
                                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 height-contact-element">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control custom-labels" id="email" placeholder="Votre courriel" required data-validation-required-message="Veuillez écrire votre courriel"/>
                                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 height-contact-element">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="message" class="form-control custom-labels" id="message" placeholder="Votre message" required data-validation-required-message="Veuillez écrire un message"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 height-contact-element">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-custom btn-noborder-radius" value="Envoyer"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 height-contact-element">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-noborder-radius btn-custom" name="reset">Réinitialiser
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 height-contact-element">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div id="response_holder"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 contact-msg">
                                    <div id="success"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-13 height-contact-element">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-map-marker"></i>
                                        <span class="text">(Bureau) 2370 Rue des Groseilliers, St-Étienne-de-Lauzon (Qc)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-13 height-contact-element">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-phone"></i>
                                        <span class="text">418-930-8214</span>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                <div class="col-md-13 height-contact-element">    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-envelope"></i>
                                        <span class="text">maisonhanteedestetienne@hotmail.com</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

**send_email.php**

```
    <?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {
    //Email information
    $admin_email = "maisonhanteedestetienne@hotmail.com";
    $name = $_REQUEST['first_name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

    //send email
    if (mail($admin_email, $name, $message, "From:" . $email)) {
        echo 1;
    }
    else {
        echo 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `De:` means "`From:`" in your language, being French. PHP/mail does not use foreign languages as core/root/basic syntax.

Comment: *"I had to translate some of the words so that they appear in French on my website"* - You cannot translate core (PHP) functions/syntax to any other language than English.

Comment: Just changed it, still nothing. But thanks !